# How to proper adding code for a class from a seperate file in PHP?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to implement some sort of plugin mechanism, to adding anonymous functions from external PHP files.

Here's the example code:

```
<?php
// class_def.php

class MyClass {
    function __construct() {
        $this->property = "some_value";
        $this->callback = array();
        include_once("plugin.php");
    }
}

$instance = new MyClass();
$instance->callback[0]();


<?php
// plugin.php
$this->callback[] = function() {
    var_dump($this->property); // Doesn't work in PHP 5.3
};
```

The code above (two files) works in PHP 5.4 but doesn't work in PHP 5.3.

So my question is: Any better idea to separate the code into two files? I may need to modify a property of an instance and access `$this` in the separate file.

Comment: Use PHP 5.4 or implement the documented workarounds

Comment: @Phil Would you mind give the link to the documented workaround? Thank you!

Comment: Here's one way - http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php#98384